# Как выбрать максимальное и минимальное значение QList<QPointF>?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть точки которые добавляются в цикле:

```
QList<QPointF> dataKmp;
QList<QPointF> dataKmpu;
for (j=1;j<1000;j++) {
  aX[j]=X/1000; 
  ...
  aKmp[j]=Kmp; aKmpu[j]=Kmpu;
  dataKmp.append(QPointF(aX[j], aKmp[j]));
  dataKmpu.append(QPointF(aX[j], aKmpu[j]));
}
```

Как выбрать aX[j] максимальное и минимальное;aKmp[j] максимальное и минимальное; aKmpu[j] максимальное и минимальное;
Чтоб потом установить диапазон:

```
axisX->setRange(min(aX[j]),max(aX[j])); // Диапазон от min(aX[j]) до max(aX[j])
axisY->setRange(min(aKmp[j],aKmpu[j]),max(aKmp[j],aKmpu[j])); 
// Диапазон от наименьшего значения aKmp[j],aKmpu[j] до наибольшего значения aKmp[j],aKmpu[j]
```

Comment: Ну как... Взять и выбрать. В процессе добавления, например. В чем именно проблема-то?

Comment: @AnT проблема описана выше. Есть функция которая сравнивает по оси X и Y значение в QList<QPointF>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно что-то такого типа:

```
QList<QPointF> dataKmp;
QList<QPointF> dataKmpu;
float xmin = 1e25;
float xmax = -1e25;
float ymin = 1e25;
float ymax = -1e25;
for (j=1;j<1000;j++) {
  aX[j]=X/1000; 
  ...
  aKmp[j]=Kmp; aKmpu[j]=Kmpu;
  dataKmp.append(QPointF(aX[j], aKmp[j]));
  dataKmpu.append(QPointF(aX[j], aKmpu[j]));

  xmin = qMin(xmin, aX[j]);
  xmax = qMax(xmax, aX[j]);
  ymin = qMin(ymin, qMin(aKmp[j], aKmpu[j]);
  ymax = qMax(ymax, qMax(aKmp[j], aKmpu[j]);
}

...

axisX->setRange(xmin, xmax);
axisY->setRange(ymin, ymax);
```

Note: скорее всего точки по X упорядочены по возрастанию и можно просто взять точку по соответствующему индексу вместо поиска xmin, xmax.

Edit: вместо значений-заглушек можно использовать `std::numeric_limits::min()` и `max()`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74333/discussion-on-answer-by-bearded-beaver------).